# Cannot find module '.../lib/providers/https

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I try to run the functions emulator with `firebase emulators:start` and get an error:

```
❯ firebase emulators:start
i  emulators: Starting emulators: functions
⚠  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: auth, firestore, database, hosting, pubsub, storage
✔  functions: Using node@14 from host.
i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log
i  functions: Watching "/Users/inlined/git/junkdrawer/functions" for Cloud Functions...
⚠  functions: Cannot find module '/Users/inlined/git/junkdrawer/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https'
Require stack:
- /Users/inlined/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js
⚠  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
```

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for this everyone, it was my fault. In version 3.15.0 and 3.15.1 of the `firebase-functions` SDK we refactored some of our file hierarchy without realizing that the emulator team monkey-patched an undocumented file/function.

The upcoming version 3.15.2 of `firebase-tools` handles both the old and new path. You can fix the error with:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Comment: Can you clarify to explicitly say what version is broken, and what version fixed that?

Comment: Always a good developer advocate. firebase-tools 3.15.0 and 3.15.1 have this problem. We will probably add a shim in 3.15.2 to fix the issue until the next breaking change.